# What is the best solution for ring-around-the-collar stains?

Tags: clothing, personal-care

Collar stains tend to be the first major sign of wear on men's dress shirts. Are there preventative measures I can take? What about reliable techniques once the stain has appeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the StackExchange community!

I listed few solutions below about reliable techniques once the stain has appeared:

- Clean a shirt collar with **liquid detergent or dishwashing liquid**

If the stains are fresh, they have not yet had the time to become encrusted. You can then apply liquid detergent directly to the collar and let it work for about ten minutes before putting the shirt in the machine, respecting the temperature indicated on the label.

- Clean a stain on a shirt collar using **baking soda**

If the traces are older, moisten the collar of your shirt with warm water and sprinkle it generously with baking soda. Rub the collar gently with a soft bristle brush. Finally, rinse with a solution of equal parts white vinegar and water. Your collar finds all its whiteness.

- Clean a shirt collar with **shampoo for oily hair**

To degrease a shirt collar, you can also add shampoo for oily hair to the stain. These shampoos contain agents that remove excess sebum from the scalp, so they are logically effective on fat spots. Rub, then pass the shirt to the washing machine.

- Clean a stain on a shirt collar with **soda crystals**

Another method of ecological cleaning: soda crystals. These 100% natural crystals are in the form of white grains similar to wet coarse salt. They are therefore more corrosive than powdered baking soda. You will find easily in all organic stores, or in supermarkets.

Instructions: dilute a tablespoon of crystals in a bowl of hot water, rub and rinse!

Source: [https://www.labelleadresse.com/](https://www.labelleadresse.com/linge/entretien-du-linge/nettoyer-col-de-chemise.html)

Comment: Thanks, the baking soda method worked wonders! Quick, easy, and I already had the ingredients at home :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that it worked ! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a group of substances for getting stains out of clothes. For white shirts and so on I use stuff called OxyClean.

There are many brands, so I won't advertise the one here. It comes as powder in a little tub and you can add a bit to your machine when washing whites. For really bad shirt collars you can mix it to a paste and let it soak in a while. I have done this on my son's uniform shirts and it's amazing. Of course you have to read the small print before use.

Not quite a lifehack, but it's not expensive so maybe this will pass.